# I want HTML Table Cell to be selected and on the screen visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I have a HTML table with around 12 cells. But in mobile screen only 4 are visible at the moment and you have to horizontally scroll in order to view the rest of the cell.
Each cell is the link to a different page and each page has the same table.
I want whenever we click on any cell that cell should become active/selected when we move to its linked page and to be visible on the screen even it is on the extreme right.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile, i would consider applying display block to all tables, rows and cells. This way, it's long, vertical, but easily browsable. Plus the scroll is vertical, which is far easier.

For your links, it's more a server side problem : you should pass the parameter corresponding to the clicked cell (let's say r2c4) in your url (mypage.php?cell=r2c4), and apply a style to the correspoding cell on your display page, with a simple class, like .activeCell.

Comment: styling is working perfectly but if the cell is in the extreme right then that is only visible when we scroll it horizontally i want it to automatically scrolled to that cell. Also I want the horizontal table only.

Comment: If you use the vertical scroll, you just have to put an id on the cell, and use its anchor.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the Answer to it
We can just simply give some id to the cell we want to display onscreen and on the link we pass the id of that cell we want to keep active and on screen visible.